# I want to get the row count of text file using console Application

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
int numOfLines1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"\\RADSpSC2\ARADA\BACKUP\Outbound\20131203\ECOMMDEMAND_20131202_ASPS.txt").Length;
Console.WriteLine(numOfLines1.ToString());

int numofLines2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"\\RADSpSC2\ARADA\BACKUP\Outbound\20131203\ECOMMDEMAND_20131202_BSPS").Length;
Console.WriteLine(numofLines2.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

But It is giving me error like `logon failure` and `bad username or password`. I am trying to enter `\\RADSpSC2` server from different server.

So how can It be possible to provide username and password inside the code?

Comment: Looks like the account your program is RUNNING UNDER does not have permissions to access this server.

Comment: @Debopam check the above possible dup. it address two possible answers: impersonation and mapping remote drive locally

Comment: what kind of applications you are creating ? an asp.net or an standalone? different application need different solutions.

Comment: @ray_linn An ASP.NET console application would be unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to authenticate your process session through the target server.

To accomplish that you have to implement exactly what the "NET USE" shell command does by executing a PInvoke to the WNetAddConnection2 (before) and WNetCancelConnection2A (after) APIs.

For example : "net use \RADSpSC2\ARADA /user: " and then "net use \RADSpSC2\ARADA /delete".

You might read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6847/Map-Network-Drive-API) and omit the drive letter to create only the session without mapping the network drive.

Comment: Devil .. What will be the changed script for this ?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your question. Could you explain it better? Do you want if provide you the coding for your example?

Comment: devil  Yes please share the coding for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no time to code, I am at work now. I suggest you to implement it by yourself using the article I have mentioned as reference. The steps are simply: connect to the share by the API example (with non drive letter), read the text file, p/invoke the cancel connection API (by the same example).